# how can i randomise the location of a widget on a window to make it different every time

Tags: random, tkinter, widget

i am trying to make a button widget that is created in a random position and everytime i click it it moves to another random position.

i have tried using the random function in the pack() parenthesis:

```
w= tkinter.Tk()
w.configure(background= 'steelblue1')
mb= tkinter.Button(w, text= 'o_o')
mb.pack(random)


w.mainloop()
```

i didn't expect this to work but was just trying it out, and this resulted in:
    object of type 'module' has no len()
what would the len() be and how do i correctly use random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place a button relative to the window you should use `place()`.

```
mb.place(x=horizontal_pos, y=vertical_pos)
```

You can do it with pack also but then you would have to generate random padding instead.

Generate random integers with the `random.uniform()` function. see examples of usage in the [random module](https://pymotw.com/3/random/index.html).